# setStatusBarStyle:animated: deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I'm currently developing an app (in Swift 3) on `Xcode 8 beta`, for `iOS 10`.

What I want to achieve is to change status bar style within a view controller at run time, for changing the theme from daytime theme to night theme.
I've found out that the method I used to use when I was developing another app in the past was deprecated, as shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622923-setstatusbarstyle) on the API reference.

However, `preferredStatusBarStyle` won't work here since I would like to change it within a single view controller.

Can anybody think of other ways to perform this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

To be clear, what I want to do is to change the style when the view controller is already on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a statusBarStyle variable that when changed updates the status bar appearance. If you only want this to affect one controller, simply reverse the effect when the Controller will or did disappear.

```
var statusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle = .lightContent {
    didSet {
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return statusBarStyle
}
```

The above solution will override the previous controller's status bar style before the controller appears. If you want to change the status bar style when the controller appears, try this:

```
var statusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle? {
    didSet {
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return statusBarStyle ?? super.preferredStatusBarStyle
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what I would like to do is changing the status bar style after the view controller is already presented. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: You would change the `statusBarStyle` variable inside your controller's `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question a little bit. I'm asking if it's possible to change the style after the view is already on screen. For example, the status bar is now default style, and when I push a button, it should turn to lightContent. Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, so you have a view controller that is already on screen and you want to change the style of status bar on a button press?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm doing that in order to make a theme change.

Answer (score -1):

In your info.plist, add the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key with a value of false.

Then, in your viewController when switching to your night theme:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

To go back to black:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
```