# iOS StatusBarStyle not changing when set to light

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar

I'm developing an app where i want the navigationBar to be invisible and have a dark background. I want the status bar colour to be white. I also want the status bar to be hidden initially.

I have set the Status Bar Style to Light

### [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4GoW.png]

But the result i get is always black colour text status bar as shown below.

### [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qgAu.png]

I have tried to set the "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO and the result was to have a hidden status bar. I also tried to have prefersStatusBarHidden returning NO but still the same.

I have tried to "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES and the result was black text. I tried to have preferredStatusBarStyle returning UIStatusBarStyleLightContent but still the same.

I'm i doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39434571)

Comment: uncheck "Hide status bar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was cause to the UINavigationController the initial view controller was embedded in. I have subclassed UINavigationController (NLNavigationController) and set the custom class of the initial navigation controller to this (NLNavigationController). In the new subclass i had this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return NO;
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

For all this to work i had to set in the info.plist

> View controller-based status bar appearance set to YES

With this changes i got the following result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x88Ae.png

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this and style no result!